# NEXT.js 14 Method Not Allowed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I was trying to create a simple post API from my NEXT.js 14 (with app routing) app. Below are the codes:

API call:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const testFunc = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/helpers/edit-file.js", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({a: 123}),
        });
        await console.log(response);
    }
    testFunc();
}, []);
```

handler (I have stripped the code down to a basic status return, this version of the code still errs):

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
        const data = req.body;
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data });
    }
}
```

directories:

```
.
├── public/
│   └── helpers/
│       └── edit-file.js
└── src/
    └── app/
        └── main_page/
            └── page.tsx
```

the response of the call was a 403:Method Not Allowed. I also have a GET call API with a similar code that works. Somehow the issue appears with POST and PUT calls. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 is not "Method not allowed" - that would be 405.

Secondly, you are trying to fetch a js file instead of a valid URL.

After that, you say you use the app directory but the API route is not in the app directory.

Lastly, the route definition (`export default async function handler(req, res)`) is not the one used in the app directory but the old definition.

If you want to keep the URL (without `.js` obviously), you need to add `route.ts` in `app/helpers/edit-file` with the following code for POST requests:

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const res = await request.json()
  return Response.json({ res })
}
```

Change the POST function name to GET or PUT or the action you need

See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers